# Is there any solution for the Plaid API testing with react nodejs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plaid

> Unable to fetch link_token: please make sure your backend server is running and that your .env file has been configured correctly.
> If you are on a Windows machine, please ensure that you have cloned the repo with symlinks turned on. You can also try checking your activity log on your Plaid dashboard.
> Error Code:
> Error Type:
> Error Message:

I face the error while I double check credentials and other things etc in Plaid APIs

I want to resolve the error I am using react typescript and node js

Comment: You need to write what API exactly you're using. Showing random error messages from random projects is not helpful. You need to write more information right now it's like asking: my code doesn't work, please help, without any details.

Comment: So, did you do the things the error message suggested? What happened when you tried them?